# Running linux on Altera Stratix 5

Tags: nios

I want to run linux on my Altera Stratix 5. One possible way is running uClinux using Nios 2. Will this approach work for the Stratix 5? Are there any other approaches to achieve this?

Comment: There's a lot of other, including open source, cpu cores, google is your friend here. You're asking for an off-site ressource/tool recommendation, so I'm afraid this is a bit off-topic.

Comment: I just want to know if I can run uCLinux using Nios 2 on the Stratix V. All I can see on the internet is support on DE0 nano. Can a similar approach be applied for the Stratix V?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can Run uClinux on Altera FPGAs easily in no time. I did it before using Altera DE2-70 and DE2-115. It will be exactly the same for Altera Stratix V.

For Altera FPGAs, the only approach to to run uClinux or other RTOS is NIOS II. However, you need to know how use Qsys or SOPC Builder in order to generate NIOS 2 based system.

To run uClinux faster in no time, download Altera university ip cores, because it contains all the required cores to develop your system in a very short time.

Comment: I couldn't find any tutorials for uCLinux on Stratix V. So I tried to repeat the steps for DE2 boards for my board. First, none of these resources are active now to be able to download the kernel directory :  
1) wget http://sopc.et.ntust.edu.tw/pub/linux/nios2-linux-20100621.tar
2) wget on niosftp.com link. Site unavailable.
3) svn co http://www.ccm.ece.vt.edu/usvn/svn/alteraApps/trunk/uClinux/ --username=anonymous --password=anonymous
Again these seem to be depreciated. Can you point me to somewhere I can get these files?